# Setting a custom principal for the ASP.NET Identity Provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am using the Microsoft.ASPNET.Identity provider and I want to set a custom principal.

Previously with FomrsAuthentication, I would have done something like this:

```
    protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

        if(authCookie != null)
        {
            using (var db = new GSCM.Logic.GSCMDatabase())
            {
                FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
                var id = new GenericIdentity(ticket.Name);
                var principal = new VmUserLogin(id);
                var found = db.LoadInternalUser(ticket.Name);
                if(found != null)
                {
                    Mapper.Map(found, principal);
                }

                HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I do something similar with the ientity provider

Comment: Why do you need to do that?

Comment: So I have access to the object in each controller action without having to load it each time

Answer (score 0):

Instead of playing with the identity and principal, I would do the following:

Create an interface for the User Information required in your application

```
public interface ICurrentUserService
    {
        VmUserLogin  CurrentUser{get; }
    }
```

Create an implementation for this interface inside your web project as below

```
public class HttpLoggedInUserService : ICurrentUserService
    {
        private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;
        private VmUserLogin _currentUser;

        public HttpLoggedInUserService(IUserRepository userRepository)
        {
            _userRepository= userRepository;
        }
        public VmUserLogin CurrentUser
        {
            get
            {
                if (_currentUser == null)
                {
                    if (HttpContext.Current.Items.Contains("CurrentUser"))
                        return HttpContext.Current.Items["CurrentUser"] as VmUserLogin ;

                    var loginName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToLower();
                    _currentUser = _userRepository.GetByLoginName(loginName);

                    HttpContext.Current.Items["CurrentUser"] = _currentUser ;
                }

                if (_currentUser == null)
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/NoAccess");
                    return null;
                }

                return _currentUser ;
            }
        }
    }
```

At last, inside your controller, just inject the ICurrentUserService

```
public class MyController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ICurrentUserService _currentUserService;

        public MyController(ICurrentUserService currentUserService)
        {
            _currentUserService = currentUserService;
        }

       public ActionResult Index()
        {
           return View(_currentUserService.CurrentUser);
        }
}
```

You have to use an IoC container, this solution will allow you to inject the current logged in user in your controller, business layer and even the data access layer if you need and none of these layer will have a knowledge of how it is retrived

Comment: but then i have to call it on every action i want to use it

Comment: It will retrieve the user from the database once and it will be cached for the rest of calls during the request life cycle, you can also save it in session if you would like or maybe in a cookie.